# How to implement practically Magento 2 as a headless solution?

Tags: magento2.3.0, integration, headless

> i want to know the process for implementation of Magento 2 as a
> headless.
>
> Actually in my case-
>
> We have some css, js and html folders and Magento 2 in another folders
> now we are trying to integrate Magento 2 Apis with frontend(i.e.
> css, js and html) using some ReactJs OR Angular Js.
>
> If you guys have any idea please guide me.

Comment: please elaborate. what exactly are you trying to integrate?

Comment: @PhilippSander i want to integrate headless magento 2 in  localhost, is it possible

Comment: elaborate your question. I have no idea what you're talking about. using magento headless can be done via the API.

Comment: @PhilippSander,as you mentioned in your point "using magento headless can be done via the API." how to achieve it.

Answer (score 0):

> Here we can find more idea about Magento 2 Headless

[Magento 2 as a headless solution](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/161470/magento-2-as-a-headless-solution)